# can't locate storage. dual boot system

Tags: dual-boot, storage

I am new to ubuntu. I am dual booting my system w/ windows 8. I have the os on a ssd I have 4 1 terabyte hhd for storage. they are set up in windows under a storage pool. when I am ubuntu the drives are not visible. how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

At this time, there is no support for "Storage Space", a feature of Windows 8, for Linux. See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/600329/data-migration-windows-8-storage-pool) on SuperUser, and [this info](http://www.acronis.com/en-us/support/documentation/AcronisBackup_11.5/index.html#23538.html) from Acronis.

Keep in mind that other Windows versions can't use this feature either.